# mvc5 - ajax call replaces all page not just the div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajaxform

I've seen this problem severall times and tried everything suggest - never the less my div is not replaced - instead all page is "replaced" 
I'm using MVC5 . 
For project reasons i can't post here the code - but this new project pretty much sums my issue.

```
public ActionResult TestPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("_pView");
    }
```

View:

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

   <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>


<div col-md-12">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestPartial", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "reportView",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}, null, new { id = "form" }))
{


    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

}
```

'm using the latest jquery version 2.1.4

Any thoughts on why this is not adding my partial view to the div? 
The partial view is just span text for this example.

Comment: Include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: been there, done that - in fact it was a typo - it's been inclued in project - not when i copy it here :/

Comment: If you are displaying a new page, then its because the scripts are not included or are in the wrong order (and you do not need the `MicrosoftAjax` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax` scripts - in fact they may be the problem)

Comment: I have fixed you formatting (you need a new line before you start a code block)